# Is there a library to render Windows metafiles to a cairo surface?

Tags: pdf, image-processing, cairo, wmf

I'm trying to implement a PDF output target in an existing application which uses Windows metafiles (specifically, Aldus Placeable Metafiles) as one of its inputs. Is there a pre-existing library to render such metafiles to a cairo surface (or some other PDF rendering library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Uniconvertor project, a by-product of the SK1 Free Software for vector drawing can work to read and write several vector image formats, including WMF and PDF:

http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor

While not a dynamic binary library, uniconvertor is a product written in Python - and can be used from other languages, if one does embed the Python interpreter in the project to make the needed function calls (or simply perform the conversions as an external process).

It is used to give the more mainstream Inkscape editor capabilities to deal with file formats such as Coreldraw's CDR.